# Integrate With Google button: Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’

Tags: google-workspace

I am trying to add Integrate With Google button to our website using the instructions at https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/button.

According to the instruction, I need to add:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"/>
```

to head and then incorporate:

```
   <g:additnow applicationid="[appid]"></g:additnow>
```

The button is not rendered. The error in browser console says:

```
Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://accounts.google.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘http://server.local:8090’).

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: `
https://apis.google.com/additnow/additnow.html?usegapi=1&applicationid=[appid]&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fserver.local%3A8090&gsrc=3p&ic=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_US.Vch8vd-lM6E.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQE%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOgsbyjgLVijKgLfaXMbki4Pxbd_A#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Claunchurl&id=I0_1517552817258&_gfid=I0_1517552817258&parent=http%3A%2F%2Fserver.local%3A8090&pfname=&rpctoken=19038946
> does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

A couple of points:

- I am loading the page using the Tomcat web server
- server.local  resolves to 127.0.0.1
- http anywhere browser extension is disabled
- The page is not being loaded in an iframe
- I tried loading platform.js without https. make no difference.

Any ideas?